# Flutter: Import the correct color values ​with the linked id from another class

Tags: list, flutter, dart, provider

I want to access the data in a list that is in another class (class RubricItem). The color must be the one with the corresponding id.

Then I would like to insert the data from the list that I called from the RubricItem class into the list that are in the Colors class. In the Colors class is the parameter id :. And depending on which ID I typed in, my "rubricColor:" should know what its value should be.

Example:

I write down the id value of the list from the Colors class 'BlueAccent', then he also has to know which color has to be written in rubricColor:. He sees 'BlueAccent' at the id: from the Colors class and compares this with the id: in the list from the RubricItem class and sees the color value in the same list from the RubricItem class and my rubricColor: value in the list the Colors class, takes the value of color from the list of the RubricItem class.

I hope you understand what I mean.
It was very difficult for me to explain.

`RubricItem` class:

```
class _RubricItemState extends State<RubricItem> {
  final List<Rubric> rubrics = [
    Rubric(
      id: 'BlueAccent',
      title: "BLUEACCENT",
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      icon: 'assets/icons/blueAC.png',
    ),
    Rubric(
      id: "Pink",
      title: "PINK",
      color: Colors.pinkAccent,
      icon: 'assets/icons/PINK.png',
    ),
    Rubric(
      id: 'GreenAccent',
      title: "GREENACCENT",
      color: Colors.greenAccent,
      icon: 'assets/icons/GreenAccent.png',
    ),
  ];
...
```

List of Color classes:

```
final List<Colorr> colors = [
  Colorr(
    id: 'BlueAccent',  // with this id he should be find the id in the List of the RubricItem() class 
    title: 'Blabla',
    rubric: '',
    rubricColor: , //(RubricItemColor)
  ),
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use maps instead of lists.

```
map<String, Rubric>
map<String, Colorr>
```

and the Strings are the ids. And then just use the ids

**Edit1: example**

I don't know if this is the best way to approach your problem but it works.

I used the key of the map as the id and removed the id from both Rubric class and Colorr class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {

  final Map<String,Rubric> rubrics = {
    'BlueAccent': Rubric(title:'BLUEACCENT',color:  Colors.blueAccent, icon:   'assets/icons/blueAC.png'),
  };
  final Map<String, Colorr> colors = {
    'BlueAccent': Colorr(title: 'title', rubric:rubrics['BlueAccent'],rubricColor: rubrics['BlueAccent'].color),
  };
}


class Rubric{
  Rubric({this.title,this.icon,this.color});
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  final String icon;
}

class Colorr{
  Colorr({this.title,this.rubric,this.rubricColor});
  final String title;
  final Rubric rubric;
  final Color rubricColor;
}
```

Comment: firstly thank you very much... but I would be happy, if you better explain that...

Comment: @Tolga np man. check the edit hope my answer helps and good luck :).